# Android camera2 api galaxy s7

Tags: java, android, video, android-camera2

I am writing an app which records video from the phone and uploads it to a server. Works fine on any device except Galaxy S7. On the Galaxy S7 recording produces a video file with audio only and either no video or one video frame. This is true in the temporary file created on the phone and not just the one uploaded to the server.
I am using the Camera2 API, and I have tried with the front and back cameras.

I have tried with my code, and these two example applications:
https://developer.android.com/samples/Camera2Video/project.html
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java

The video file produced appears to be ok, here is the codec info:
Stream 0
Type: Video
Codec: H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1)
Language: English
Resolution: 960x720
Display resolution: 960x720
Frame rate: 29.055091

Stream 1
Type: Audio
Codec: MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)
Language: English
Channels: Stereo
Sample rate: 16000 Hz

Comment: I analysed the video file further and it is reporting the framerate and minimum framerate to be 0 fps, that might be a clue. I do specifically set the framerate to 30 though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several days of work I found the answer.

The Samsung Galaxy S7 (and S6 I think) has a bug which messes up the encoding.
The fix is to reencode using the function below.

Note that you need this dependency in your gradle:
    compile 'com.googlecode.mp4parser:isoparser:1.1.22'

```
    public void fixSamsungBug()
{
    DataSource channel = null;
    try
    {
        channel = new FileDataSourceImpl(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    IsoFile isoFile = null;

    try
    {
        isoFile = new IsoFile(channel);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    List<TrackBox> trackBoxes = isoFile.getMovieBox().getBoxes(TrackBox.class);
    boolean sampleError = false;
    for (TrackBox trackBox : trackBoxes) {
        TimeToSampleBox.Entry firstEntry = trackBox.getMediaBox().getMediaInformationBox().getSampleTableBox().getTimeToSampleBox().getEntries().get(0);

        // Detect if first sample is a problem and fix it in isoFile
        // This is a hack. The audio deltas are 1024 for my files, and video deltas about 3000
        // 10000 seems sufficient since for 30 fps the normal delta is about 3000
        if(firstEntry.getDelta() > 10000) {
            sampleError = true;
            firstEntry.setDelta(3000);
        }
    }

    if(sampleError) {
        Log.d("gpinterviewandroid", "Sample error! correcting...");
        Movie movie = new Movie();
        for (TrackBox trackBox : trackBoxes) {
            movie.addTrack(new Mp4TrackImpl(channel.toString() + "[" + trackBox.getTrackHeaderBox().getTrackId() + "]" , trackBox));
        }
        movie.setMatrix(isoFile.getMovieBox().getMovieHeaderBox().getMatrix());
        Container out = new DefaultMp4Builder().build(movie);

        //delete file first!
        File file = new File(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL);
        boolean deleted = file.delete();


        FileChannel fc = null;
        try
        {
            //fc = new FileOutputStream(new File(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL)).getChannel();
            fc = new RandomAccessFile(app.dataMgr.videoFileURL, "rw").getChannel();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            out.writeContainer(fc);
            fc.close();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("gpinterviewandroid", "Finished correcting raw video");
    }
}
```